# Partial selector and matching

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have ten product listed on a web page and use code below to bind css class to show selection. As you can see I have duplicate the same code for every product. I am not good in jQuery, maybe someone could suggest optimization to get rid of duplicate code?

```
$('.product1').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {     
  $('.product1').has('div').closest("tr").children("td").not('.product1').toggleClass('product1-selected');
});

$('.product2').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {  
     $('.product2').has('div').closest("tr").children("td").not('.product2').toggleClass('product2-selected');
});

$('.product3').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {    
   $('.product3').has('div').closest("tr").children("td").not('.product3').toggleClass('product3-selected');
});

//and so on
```

HTML

```
<table class="product-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th class="product1">
            Free
        </th>
        <th class="product2">
            Basic
        </th>
        <th class="product3">
            Premium
        </th>
        <th class="product4">
            Elite
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>     
        </td>
        <td class="price product1">
        </td>
        <td class="price product2">
            5.00 USD/Month
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 PayPal &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=8VVZ8YWHZGNGC&amp;custom_user_id='" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 Plimus &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=2296795&amp;custom_user_id='" />
        </td>
        <td class="price product3">
            15.00 USD/Month
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 PayPal &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=NZ7TR9A3ZHZHS&amp;custom_user_id='" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 Plimus &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=2296795&amp;custom_user_id='" />
        </td>
        <td class="price product4">
            25.00 USD/Month
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 PayPal &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=W5VU287ZC2USQ&amp;custom_user_id='" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up 
 Plimus &raquo;" onclick="window.location='https://www.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=2296805&amp;custom_user_id='" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Instant activation
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            For personal use
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            For organizational & business needs
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Number of conversions per month
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
            <div>30</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>100</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>Unlimited</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>Unlimited</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            PDF by e-mail usage
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
            <div>30</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>100</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>Unlimited</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>Unlimited</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Create up to 20 additional memberships for free
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Removed Web2PDF logo from PDF's
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Remove ads
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Set and Save PDF options
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Conversion statistics
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            You will help us to keep this service running, add more features and grow
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Personal support
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            New features on demand
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Integration support
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="feature">
            Priority in development queue
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product1">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product2">
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product3">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
        <td class="feature-marker product4">
            <div>X</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please also post your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using id attributes for product1, product2, etc., and then give each product a class of "product". Then you can attach a single event to all products, like so:

```
<th id="product1" class="product">
    Free
</th>

<th id="product2" class="product">
    Basic
</th>

<td id="price1" class="price">
</td>
<td id="price2" class="price">
</td>
```

```
$('.product').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {     

    var $product = jQuery(this);
    var id = $product.attr('id');
    var num = id.replace("product", "");

    // Your desired logic follows:

    $('#price'+num).addClass('selected');

    $('.price').not('#price'+num).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I can't use ID selector because it duplicate object and   var $product = jQuery(this); var id = $product.attr('id'); code will return Null. Tested and do not work!

Comment: @Tomas: My mistake, I hadn't seen your HTML. I'm not sure I understand the logic you want, but the changes I made to my code should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your exact jQuery code you can reduce it to this more readable version:

```
for (var i = 1, len = 3; i < len; i++) {
    var $product = $('.product' + i);
    $product.hover(function () {
        $product
            .has('div')
            .closest('tr')
            .children('td')
            .not($product)
            .toggleClass('product'+ i +'-selected');
    });
}
```

But I think there must be a different, better approach to what you're trying to do. I would start by using a generic class like `.product` and use an id for the name or number of each product. Same with the `selected` class. Then I'm pretty sure this selector can be improved, can't really tell with your code though.

```
$('.product1').has('div').closest("tr").children("td").not('.product1').toggleClass('product1-selected');
```

Comment: It seems there is problem with your code. toggleClass('product'+ i +'-selected' always return the last iteration in the loop, in your case 3. It seems number is passed by reference and not as new object.